# Runtime of this iterative combinations algorithm

Tags: performance, big-o, combinatorics

I have found the following algorithm [online](https://www.baeldung.com/java-combinations-algorithm) which, given a length `n` of an array and a number `k` of indices to select, produces all the possible combinations of `k` indices. I have implemented it here:

```
def combinations(n, k):
    combinations = []
    combination = [None]*k

    for i in range(k):
        combination[i] = i

    while combination[k - 1] < n:
        combinations.append(combination.copy())

        t = k - 1
        while t != 0 and combination[t] == n - k + t:
            t -= 1
        combination[t] += 1

        for i in range(t + 1, k):
            combination[i] = combination[i - 1] + 1

    return combinations


n, k = 4, 2
print(combinations(n, k))
```

(I am aware that Python's `itertools` could be used to produce this, however I aim to use this in Java, and have only written it in Python here for readability and easy testing.)

As an example, if we have an array `[0,1,2,3]` (with length `n=4`) and want to select `k=2` indices, this will produce:

`[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]`

My time-analysis skills have grown a bit rusty: how would I go about determining the big-O runtime of this algorithm? Or, is this a well-known algorithm that anyone recognizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial estimate is *O(choose(n,k)*k)*, where *choose(n,k)* is the number of combinations.
Indeed, the main `while` loop body is entered as many times as is the number of items in the answer.
And each time, each of the two inner loops finishes in *O(k)*.

There might be a tighter upper bound if *n* and *k* are in some special relation.
For example, if *k~n/2*, I believe the *k* multiplier vanishes, leaving just *O(choose(n,k))*.
But the bound is tight at least for the *k=n-1* case.

Comment: This makes perfect sense to me, thank you!